# Postgres Function not working when I have a large result

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.5

I'm copying information from table 1(tmp_subtype) to table 2(subtype_user). I have a test table 1 with 15 registers. I run this function into postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VERIFY_AND_INSERT_SUPTYPE()
    RETURNS text AS $$
    DECLARE
       register_subtype RECORD;
       existe INT DEFAULT 0;
       MESSAGE_EXCEPTION TEXT;
       cursor_subtype CURSOR
       FOR
          SELECT tsd.subtype,tsd.type_id_client,tsd.id_client,tsd.email
          FROM tmp_subtype tsd;
    BEGIN

      OPEN cursor_subtype;
      LOOP
         FETCH cursor_subtype INTO register_subtype;
         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO existe FROM (
            SELECT sdu.id_client FROM subtype_user sdu
            WHERE sdu.id_client = register_subtype.id_client AND sdu.type_id_client = register_subtype.type_id_client
            LIMIT 1
         ) SUB0;

         IF existe = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO subtype_user(subtype,type_id_client,id_client,email)
            VALUES (register_subtype.subtype,register_subtype.type_id_client,register_subtype.id_client,register_subtype.email);
         ELSE
            UPDATE subtype_user sdu2 SET subtype=register_subtype.subtype,email=register_subtype.email
            WHERE sdu2.id_client = register_subtype.id_client AND sdu2.type_id_client = register_subtype.type_id_client;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cursor_subtype;

      RETURN 'OK';

      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS MESSAGE_EXCEPTION = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            RETURN MESSAGE_EXCEPTION;
    END; $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It works, but When I run this function with the real table 1, it is not working. The function finishes but nothing happend. The real table 1 has 1 million of registers.

Comment: With "registers", do you mean "rows"?

Comment: Yes, I do. Register=row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row-by-row processing with embedded counting is a recipe for slow and inefficient processing. Additionally your check for existence won't work if the function is invoked from concurrent transactions. As far as I can tell you can replace the whole loop and cursor with a single INSERT statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VERIFY_AND_INSERT_SUPTYPE()
    RETURNS text 
AS $$
DECLARE
  MESSAGE_EXCEPTION TEXT;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO subtype_user(subtype, type_id_client, id_client, email)
  SELECT tsd.subtype, tsd.type_id_client, tsd.id_client, tsd.email
  FROM tmp_subtype tsd
  ON conflict (id_client, type_id_client) DO UPDATE 
    SET  subtype = excluded.register_subtype,
         email = excluded.email;

  RETURN 'OK';

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS MESSAGE_EXCEPTION = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        RETURN MESSAGE_EXCEPTION;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I probable would not add an exception handler to begin with, so that the caller sees the complete exception.

Comment: I've executed the function with limit 10 and offset 0 and  my postgres not response after 5 minutes. Use  ctrl+c and the console shows:
`Cancel request sent
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (658,8) in relation "subtype_user"` Why postgres does nothing? Postgres is in a machine with 2 gb RAM

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say, what is wrong on this code - in this situation `RAISE NOTICE` is your best friend. I see some issues in your code, but these issues are related to performance. Table with 1 mil rows is nothing.

1. the code in ISAM programming style can be really slow - instead cycle over cursor use `INSERT ON CONFLICT ..` [statement](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/).
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` can be rewritten to little bit faster, but surely more readable form:

   ```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT ... FROM subtype_user) THEN
     UPDATE ...
   ELSE
     INSERT ...
   END IF;
   ```
3. Handling errors from your example is little bit obsolete - catch only exception that you can really solve. Your type of exception handling doesn't solve any, and more, you lose details info about the exception (position, line, ...). Just don't do it.